# Python random number list organizer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = [37,20,3,2,66,5]
oglist = []
a = list[0]
while len(list) > 2:
    for i in list:
        if a <= i:
            continue
        else :
            a = i
            continue
    oglist.append(a)
    list.pop(list.index(a))
print(oglist)
```

I keep getting an error at list.pop saying x doesn't exist in list

Comment: firstly, you are overriding the keyword `list`. which is a NO NO!

Comment: you're probably setting the same value several times in `a`. Try to print `a`

Comment: You have to put `a = list[0]` into the `while` loop, otherwise it is stuck on a value that you already popped from the list. Also, your "algorithm" seems to be identical to `mylist = sorted(mylist)[:-2]`.

Comment: @BlackBeard `list` isn't a keyword. If it was, it wouldn't be possible to assign to it.

Comment: @BlackBeard You are right, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name - it is shadowing the class `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was stated in a comment, you are overriding the class name `list`.
Another issue I see is that `a` is not reset each time you go through the loop : after first passage, `a`'s value is 66, and it stays 66 until the end.

```
randomList = [37,20,3,2,66,5]
sortedList = []
while len(randomList) > 0:
    a = randomList[0]
    for i in randomList:
        if a <= i:
            continue
        else :
            a = i
            continue
    sortedList.append(a)
    randomList.pop(randomList.index(a))
print(sortedList)
```

I moved the `a = randomList[0]` inside the while loop, so that the value of a is always that of an element present in the list.
I also changed the condition to `len(randomList)>0` so that i keeps sorting until the argument list is empty

Comment: @khelwood I modified my answer, as `list` is indeed not a keywords, but a class name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your prime problem, this is a simple solution.

```
import random
lists = []
for a in range(10):
    lists.append(random.randint(1, 10))

print "lists",sorted(lists)
```